# Saving the updated coordinates of a moved QGraphicsLineItem

Tags: qt, save, line, coordinates, move

I am adding a line with two mouse clicks, for each of the end points of a line. The line's class is inherited from `QGraphicsLineItem`.

I save the line using `QXmlStreamWriter` and thus both the end points are saved for the line. The following section of code writes start and end points for line:

```
stream->writeAttribute("x1", QString::number(myItem->line().p1().x()));
stream->writeAttribute("y1", QString::number(myItem->line().p1().y()));
stream->writeAttribute("x2", QString::number(myItem->line().p2().x()));
stream->writeAttribute("y2", QString::number(myItem->line().p2().y()));
```

where `stream` is a pointer of `QXmlStreamWriter` and `myItem` is pointer of line's class.

This works good until I move the line from its original position in scene to another position in scene.

Even the line is displaced from its original position, I continue to get the end points of the original position when I save my file. I want to save the updated coordinates of the line after it is moved to another position in the scene. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What the `myItem->line` points to?

Comment: Oops! That is line() function of `QGraphicsLineItem` class. I missed out the parenthesis.

Comment: Did you set the line with `QGraphicsLineItem::setLine()`?